# Yield output from fixture function after teardown

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, fixtures

I am writing a function for setup and tear down using Pytest fixture

```
@pytest.fixture
def fixture_fun():
    #setup 
    yield output #yield the output from setup
    #teardown
```

and I apply this to the test function

```
def test_fixture_fn(fixture_fn):
    #assert something from output
```

I can only yield the output in between setup and teardown. Is there anyway to get the the status of teardown from the fixture?

My requirement is given below:

```
 @pytest.fixture
    def fixture_fun():
        #setup 
        yield output #yield the output from setup
        #teardown
        yield teardown_status 

def test_fixture_fn(fixture_fn):
    #assert something from output
    assert teardown_status == True
```

I know the above one is bit illogical. Is there anyway to achieve it?

Comment: Well it wouldn't be teardown if you were still within the test.  Teardown is after the test has already finished.  This question makes no sense.

Comment: I got it. I was looking for some possibilities. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: You can put some teardown assertions directly into the fixture function.

Comment: @wim That worked. Thank you!